# How do I conditionally call a gauss function in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, gauss

I have a search index for my website which has (among others) the following fields:

type
title
body
published_at

What I want to do is execute the following gauss function only when type='article':

```
        {
          "gauss": {
            "published_at": {
              "scale": "14d",
              "offset": "7d",
              "decay": 0.95
            }
          }
        },
```

Basically, I want to keep all types of search results relevant, but articles are allowed to age and slowly fall down the ranking.

Can anyone help me with this, because I cannot work it out.

Here is the complete function_score, which includes weighting for different values of type:

```
    "function_score": {
      "functions": [
        {
          "gauss": {
            "published_at": {
              "scale": "14d",
              "offset": "7d",
              "decay": 0.95
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "match": {
              "type": "programme"
            }
          },
          "weight": 60
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "match": {
              "type": "podcast"
            }
          },
          "weight": 50
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "match": {
              "type": "article"
            }
          },
          "weight": 40
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "match": {
              "type": "clip"
            }
          },
          "weight": 30
        }
      ],
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to move the `gauss` function to where you have the filter on `type: article`:

```
  "function_score": {
    "functions": [
      {
        "filter": {
          "match": {
            "type": "programme"
          }
        },
        "weight": 60
      },
      {
        "filter": {
          "match": {
            "type": "podcast"
          }
        },
        "weight": 50
      },
      {
        "filter": {
          "match": {
            "type": "article"
          }
        },
        "gauss": {
          "published_at": {
            "scale": "14d",
            "offset": "7d",
            "decay": 0.95
          }
        },
        "weight": 40
      },
      {
        "filter": {
          "match": {
            "type": "clip"
          }
        },
        "weight": 30
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: @garethwi Any issue with this? it was 2021, maybe we need to revise the query a little bit.